# Copy local file to remote AWS EC2 instance with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, packer

I'm attempting to build an AWS AMI using both Packer and Ansible to provision my AMI. I'm getting stuck on being able to copy some local files to my newly spun up EC2 instance using Ansible. I'm using the `copy` module in Ansible to do this. Here's what my Ansible code looks like:

```
    - name: Testing copy of the local remote file
      copy:
        src: /tmp/test.test
        dest: /tmp
```

Here's the error I get:

```
 amazon-ebs: TASK [Testing copy of the local remote file] ***********************************

 amazon-ebs: fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unable to find '/tmp/test.test' in expected paths."}
```

I've verified that the file `/tmp/test.test` exists on my local machine from which Ansible is running.

For my host file I just have `localhost` in it since packer is telling Ansible everything it needs to know about where to run Ansible commands.

I'm not sure where to go from here or how to properly debug this error, so I'm hoping for a little help.

Here's what my Packer script looks like:

```
  {
  "variables": {
    "aws_access_key": "{{env `access_key`}}",
    "aws_secret_key": "{{env `secret_key`}}"
  },
  "builders": [{
    "type": "amazon-ebs",
    "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
    "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "source_ami": "ami-116d857a",
    "instance_type": "t2.micro",
    "ssh_username": "admin",
    "ami_name": "generic_jenkins_image",
    "ami_description": "Testing AMI building with Packer",
    "vpc_id": "xxxxxxxx",
    "subnet_id": "xxxxxxxx",
    "associate_public_ip_address": "true",
    "tags": {"Environment" : "Dev", "Product": "SharedOperations"}
  }],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "inline": [
        "sleep 30",
        "sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock",
        "sudo apt-get update -y --fix-missing",
        "sudo apt-get -y install libpq-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libffi-dev gcc build-essential python-pip",
        "sudo pip install ansible"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "ansible-local",
      "playbook_file": "ansible/main.yml"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's my entire Ansible file:

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Testing copy of the local remote file
      copy:
        src: /tmp/test.test
        dest: /tmp
```

Comment: @techraf Not 100% sure why it's giving that address, but I do know that's the EC2 instance. I've run some other commands (like user creation) to make sure my Ansible script is actually executing on the remote host and not my local host.

Comment: The only think I can think of is that Packer is just taking my Ansible script and pushing it out to the newly minted EC2 instance and then running it. In which case, of course this file move is going to fail since it doesn't exists. I'm not 100% sure on that though, since I'm not totally sure how this is working under the covers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [ansible-local provisioner](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible-local.html) which runs the playbooks directly on targets ("local" in HashiCorp's products like Vagrant, Packet is used to describe the point of view of the provisioned machine).

The target does not have the `/tmp/test.test` file, hence you get the error.

You actually want to run the playbook using the regular [Ansible provisioner](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html).

Comment: After you pointed out the obvious `127.0.0.1` address that I was ignoring for some reason, that dawned on me. I'm guessing I want to use the [Ansible Remote](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html) provisioner... Thanks!